# Unable to insert data into mongodb through python

Tags: python, mongodb

For a project I am using Mongodb with python. When I tried to connect to the database and insert the data, I was able to get the id back from the insert command but when I checked the database from the command prompt the data is not there. the log file shows that the connection was build and then closed nut not for the inserted data.
code:

```
database = "btp"
collect = "first"

#connecting to the mongodb
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.database
collection = db.collect
collectd = db.collect
name2 = 'name'
id = collection.insert({name2:'demo document'})
print id
```

any guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Dictionary style access

`db = client[database]
collection = db[collect]`

Comment: To elaborate, when you use dot notation as you did in your example, it is not pulling in the value associated with your variable database, but the literal "database" string.  In mongo you would do mongo; use database; db.collection.find() and your documents would be there.  However, using the dict style will use the variable rather than the literal string which is what you want

Comment: So simple..I have been looking for a solution for hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written you're code, the data should be in a collection named "collect" that is in a database named "database".

When you want to get a handle for a collection, you call either `db['collection_name']`, or `db.collection_name`. What you've done here is `db.variable_name`, which will be a different collection than you were expecting. Similar for getting handle for a database.

One thing you have to get used to about MongoDB (and is a nice feature once you are used to it) is that if a database or collection doesn't exist, it will allow you to access it as if it did and create it when you insert data.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of pymongo (year 2021, version 3.12 and above) now supports the use of dots and dollar signs in document field names/keys.
Previously only the MongoDB server supported it and thus pymongo was still throwing errors, but now, current versions of both pymongo and MondoDB all support it. Check the respective pymongo github commits here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/commit/ccb62d4c1bed0817f635bd2e0aaa822adf606027

Currently I'm able to insert dots with the following pymongo and MongoDB versions
pymongo version: 3.12.1
MongoDB version: 4.6...

Find related comments on MongoDB docs page here (Ctrl f "dots"):
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#std-label-crud-concepts-dot-dollar-considerations